# How to denote the type of function unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

all.

I have some question about how to denote a certain type of function.
Assuming $A$, $A'$, $B$, $B'$ are four sets where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.
Is there a standard way to denote the set of all functions $f\colon (A \cup B) \to (A' \cup B')$, such that $\forall x\in A \colon f(x)\in A'$ and $\forall x\in B \colon f(x)\in B'$.

Many thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't think there is a conventional notation for this. You are  really two  sticking together two functions. If you think of a function as a set of ordered pairs then this is really just $f \cup g$; you could go with that. Just be sure to explain to your reader.

Comment: post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However, what i am looking for is not really about sticking together two single functions but a way to compose function types (sets of functions).

Comment: You may be looking for a type system with _intersection types_, in which you could write $(A\to A')\cap (B\to B')$ (though note that this depends on interpreting the $\to$ type constructor in a way that meshes well with the intersection operation).